# DevExpress MVC GridView: Using DetailRowGetButtonVisibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, show-hide, master-detail

Is it possible to use the event RowGetButtonVisibility in ASP.NET MVC?
In "normal" ASP.NET DevExpress is using this like described here:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_DetailRowGetButtonVisibilitytopic

I want to have the possibility to show/hide the detail button within the GridView.

Any ideas to do this?

Something like this is not working:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<FOO>" %>
<%
Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "resultsTable";
    settings.KeyFieldName = "ResultId";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Results", Action = "ResultsPartial" };
    settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);

    //...

    settings.PreRender = (sender, e) =>
    {
        MVCxGridView grid = (MVCxGridView)sender;
        grid.DetailRowGetButtonVisibility += (s_, e_) =>
        {
            if (some_condition == true)
            e_.ButtonState = GridViewDetailRowButtonState.Hidden;
        };
    };
})
.Bind(Model.Results)
.Render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem as described in the DevExpress-Forum here:

http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/105806/358003.aspx#358003

My first try with attaching to the event was right, but not at PreRender. DataBound is the right event to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think I will go with pure html button inside the `SetDataItemTemplateContent`.

I did something like that to handle the output of a link using a simple `if` that you can extend. I guess it should work also for you.

```
var linkWeb = settings.Columns.Add("", "Web");
linkWeb.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
{
   DevExpressHelper.WriteLineToResponse((DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "UrlWeb") != null && DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "UrlWeb") != "") ? "<a href=\"" + DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "UrlWeb") + "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Url\"><img src=\"" + Url.Content("~/content/img/url.png") + "\" alt=\"Url\" /></a>" : "");
});
```

Inside this html code you could attach a call to the callback action you need. If i remember right, it should be something like that

```
mygrid.UpdateEdit();
```

Hope it helps.